# How can I change text automatically with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, text, greasemonkey

I want to change (text name) automatically with Greasemonkey.

For example, I want to see "false" instead of "Boxing" and "Kickbox".

`< text >Boxing< /text >` = `< text >false< /text >`

`< text >Kickbox< /text >` = `< text >false< /text >`

`< text >Football< /text >` = `< text >true< /text >`

**I want to change this code:**

```
< questions >
    < question id="5" >
        < text >Which is playing with ball ?< /text >
        < answer id="10" >
            < text >Boxing< /text >
        < /answer >
        < answer id="11" >
            < text >Football< /text >
        < /answer >
        < answer id="12" >
            < text >Kickbox< /text >
        < /answer >
    < /question >
< /questions >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best as I can interpret the question (please clarify and link to the actual page or a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) of the actual page, here is a complete script that changes those values:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Automatically change answer text
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

changeAnswerText ("Boxing",     "false");
changeAnswerText ("Kickbox",    "false");


function changeAnswerText (oldText, newText) {
    //-- oldText is case-sensitive.
    var answers = $("questions answer text:contains('" + oldText + "')");
    answers.text (newText);
}
```